# Bootstrap : Using custom image for file upload

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have to use given image for file upload button  using bootstrap 3 to customize the button look i used this

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
    <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display:none;">
    Button Text Here
</label>
```

but there are 5 image upload buttons  and fr one of these I've to use a specific graphic provided how can i use that ?

Comment: Are you trying to use an image as a button? If so you can add `background-image: url('image/url.png');` as CSS to the button element.

Comment: yes i am trying that , so bg image will be fine ?

Comment: Should be. Give it a try and report back if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you will need to put a `span` or a `div` as a background image via css like the below

**html**

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
    <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display:none;">
        <span id="image">Text</span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
#image {background-image:url of the image}
```